# Не работает плагин YouTrack в PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, youtrack

При нажатии на Configure ничего не происходит

[image: При нажатии на Configure ничего не происходит]

Comment: Кнопка с помощью которой получилось добавить параметры подключения находилась на верхней панеле задач справа

Answer (score 0):

Кнопка с помощью которой получилось добавить параметры подключения находилась на верхней панеле задач справа